# Interstitial screen/marketing layer on Airport guest wifi

Tags: network, wifi, airport

Is there a way I can add an interstitial screen when a user first logs in to my Airport Extreme's guest network whereby I can make a marketing ask (like, "Like us on Facebook!") and require them to check a box and click a button ("I accept the terms of service," etc.) before continuing to browse the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a **Captive Portal**.

You can't create captive portals solely with an AirPort Extreme—you need at least a computer behind the network set up as DCHP/DNS/etc. You're going to need to configure a Mac to provide DNS to redirect the first visit from a device to a hosted site.

For more information about creating a captive portal yourself, see:

- http://brewstersoft.com/blog/setting-up-a-captive-portal.html

Commercial software is available which can set this up for you:

- http://patronsoft.com/firstspot/

Comment: know of any good open source alternatives to firstspot? $500+ is quite pricey!

Comment: @selfagency Nope :(

Comment: I figured out a way to do it way cheaper. I can get a $30 TP-Link router, then install CoovaAP, which is open source OpenWRT-compatible Captive Portal firmware, then use the TP-Link router as my gateway for guests.

Answer (score -2):

your looking to do something like what the Wavespot (router) does, its a social wifi authentication gateway that allows people to sign into a wifi network using email or Facebook 'Like' (or twitter or Google Plus). Good service and we use it for a few of our agency (bluntagency.com) clients, predominantly shopping centre's.